# Flask GET command: TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable

Tags: postgresql, flask

I am currently building a website using Reactjs, Flask, and PostgreSQL. My PostgreSQL database is made up of entirely String and integer type columns, except for one (called url and of type bytea). Whenever I try to fetch the image using the GET call and return a json format to the frontend React side, I get the "TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable" error. The images were originally converted to bytea format using the psycopg2.Binary() method.

This is my get code in Flask:

```
def format_event(event):
    return {
        "name": event.name,
        "id": event.id, 
        "url" : event.url,
        "type": event.type,
        "width": event.width,
        "height": event.height
    }

#get all events
@app.route('/events', methods=['GET'])
def get_events():
    events = Event.query.order_by(Event.id.asc()).all()
    event_list = []
    for event in events:
        event_list.append(format_event(event))
    return {'events' : event_list}
```

This is the traceback:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\joshu\.virtualenvs\backend-N0JzJpE8\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1463, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
               
  File "C:\Users\joshu\.virtualenvs\backend-N0JzJpE8\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 873, in full_dispatch_request
    return self.finalize_request(rv)
           
  File "C:\Users\joshu\.virtualenvs\backend-N0JzJpE8\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 892, in finalize_request
    response = self.make_response(rv)
              
  File "C:\Users\joshu\.virtualenvs\backend-N0JzJpE8\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1183, in make_response
    rv = self.json.response(rv)
         
  File "C:\Users\joshu\.virtualenvs\backend-N0JzJpE8\Lib\site-packages\flask\json\provider.py", line 214, in response
    f"{self.dumps(obj, **dump_args)}\n", mimetype=self.mimetype
       
  File "C:\Users\joshu\.virtualenvs\backend-N0JzJpE8\Lib\site-packages\flask\json\provider.py", line 179, in dumps
    return json.dumps(obj, **kwargs)
           
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_3.12.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\json\__init__.py", line 238, in dumps
    **kw).encode(obj)
          
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_3.12.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\json\encoder.py", line 200, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
             
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_3.12.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\json\encoder.py", line 258, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
           
  File "C:\Users\joshu\.virtualenvs\backend-N0JzJpE8\Lib\site-packages\flask\json\provider.py", line 121, in _default
    raise TypeError(f"Object of type {type(o).__name__} is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable
```

Note that my Flask file is called app.py

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Don't make us guess where the error happens.  Post the full python error traceback message.

Comment: @JohnGordon just fixed it